# How do I determine file type in Linux?

Tags: kubuntu, configuration, ls

I'm editing the LS_COLORS environment variable. `dircolors` lists the default colors for different file types. The file types are denoted as follows:

```
bd = (BLOCK, BLK)   Block device (buffered) special file
cd = (CHAR, CHR)    Character device (unbuffered) special file
di = (DIR)  Directory
do = (DOOR) [Door][1]
ex = (EXEC) Executable file (ie. has 'x' set in permissions)
fi = (FILE) Normal file
ln = (SYMLINK, LINK, LNK)   Symbolic link. If you set this to ‘target’ instead of a numerical value, the color is as for the file pointed to.
mi = (MISSING)  Non-existent file pointed to by a symbolic link (visible when you type ls -l)
no = (NORMAL, NORM) Normal (non-filename) text. Global default, although everything should be something
or = (ORPHAN)   Symbolic link pointing to an orphaned non-existent file
ow = (OTHER_WRITABLE)   Directory that is other-writable (o+w) and not sticky
pi = (FIFO, PIPE)   Named pipe (fifo file)
sg = (SETGID)   File that is setgid (g+s)
so = (SOCK) Socket file
st = (STICKY)   Directory with the sticky bit set (+t) and not other-writable
su = (SETUID)   File that is setuid (u+s)
tw = (STICKY_OTHER_WRITABLE)    Directory that is sticky and other-writable (+t,o+w)
```

How do I determine which of these categories a file or directory belongs to?

Links I'm referencing for LS_COLORS:

- [Configuring LS_COLORS](http://www.bigsoft.co.uk/blog/2008/04/11/configuring-ls_colors)
- [COLORS-Lscolors](http://www.linux-sxs.org/housekeeping/lscolors.html)

Using `file` is not working; querying a directory tells me the directory is... a directory. But clearly it has a filetype flag that `file` is not displaying, because some directories have an absolutely awful pale-green highlight with white text. Using `ls -lah` does not work either; the first letter of the permissions string is `d` and this again is not enough information.

Ubuntu 19.10 | KDE Plasma 5.16.5 | zsh 5.7.1

Comment: Check if the permissions on those folders are different than the rest.  That is what I usually find that is coloring my directories oddly.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I don't know of a program that will list the file type as `dircolors` knows it. I suspect there isn't, though it would be a nice addition to dircolors But you can dump the database and find there the ones you want to change. For example, for directories:

```
$ dircolors -p|grep dir

# Configuration file for dircolors, a utility to help you set the
# slackware version of dircolors) are recognized but ignored.
DIR 01;34 # directory
STICKY_OTHER_WRITABLE 30;42 # dir that is sticky and other-writable (+t,o+w)
OTHER_WRITABLE 34;42 # dir that is other-writable (o+w) and not sticky
STICKY 37;44 # dir with the sticky bit set (+t) and not other-writable
```

Now you know just how many different types of directories there are (for `dicolors`, they are just directories for `file`. Check the permissions of the white on pale-green directory with `ls -ld your_directory`

You can also list the colors with their meaning, in your system. Check [this script](https://github.com/gkotian/gautam_linux/blob/master/scripts/colours.sh).

I know these steps do not do exactly what you want: get the file type dircolors uses for a certain node. But, between the two they should help debug and you adjust your colors for those file types you cannot otherwise find.